# ionic background geolocation stop working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, tracking, android-gps

whit this code i can get gps data and retrive address all works fine in background, for some minuts, after 20 minuts about,the app semms stop do what i aspect.
i tryed battery concession and other possible things, ive tryed backgroud service.
But nothing seems to wor for get position in background, after lomg time.
Any suggestion.

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then(() => {


console.log('backgroundGeolocation configconfigconfigconfigconfigconfig');

this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

    console.log(location);  
    this.ngZone.run(() => {


        this.geolocationService.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(location.latitude, 
        location.longitude).then((result: NativeGeocoderResult[]) =>{

      console.log("JSON.stringify(result[0]",JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            this.comunenoreplace = result[0]['locality'];
            this.comune = result[0]['locality'].replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");
            this.provincia = result[0]['subAdministrativeArea'].replace(new RegExp('Città Metropolitana di|Provincia di', 'g'), '');
            this.globalLatitude = location.latitude;
            this.globalLongitude = location.longitude;


          }).catch((error: any) => console.log("reverseGeocode", error));


    });
    // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
    // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your operations are successful or not.
    // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
   // this.backgroundGeolocation.finish;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode

it just modify the sleep mode for apps to make them work in background (without killing the process).

If the process is killed, so the app may stop sending datas.

Then you have "cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.excludeFromTaskList()"; to make it disappear from the tasklist (Android 5.0+)

Hope this help :)